# Is there a faster Python algorithm to iterate through grouped Cartesian product pairs?

Tags: python, join, cartesian-product, group

I have two files (*lhs* and *rhs*), each with a grouping-variable field (other variables exist too).

The goal is to iterate through the [Cartesian product](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Noun) pairs within each grouping-variable value as quickly as possible. There may be grouping-variable values unique to only the lhs or unique to only the rhs, and these items are to be ignored.

So I am really only looking for Cartesian product pairs where the lhs/rhs grouping-variable values are equal. The iteration through the lhs/rhs pairs involves a trivial variable length comparison for illustration purposes.

In reality, the pair processing involves a series of function calls. The grouping-variable value creation has also been simplified. In reality, it is created in a dynamic fashion from external file parameters.

My example is also simplified by just using English-dictionary words. Also, I do not want to sort the data because the real data is large. I have provided my current code, which provides the correct result.

My current strategy for quick access is a manual indexing process using dictionary data-types. Is there a faster way?

This is my current (simplified) code example, which functions correctly:

```
lhs_data = [{'lhs_id':'001', 'word':'clean'},
            {'lhs_id':'002', 'word':'stop'},
            {'lhs_id':'003', 'word':'those'}]
rhs_data = [{'rhs_id':'001', 'word':'quack'},
            {'rhs_id':'002', 'word':'step'},
            {'rhs_id':'003', 'word':'stir'},
            {'rhs_id':'004', 'word':'state'},
            {'rhs_id':'005', 'word':'storm'},
            {'rhs_id':'006', 'word':'thin'},
            {'rhs_id':'008', 'word':'thaw'},
            {'rhs_id':'009', 'word':'thorn'},
            {'rhs_id':'010', 'word':'thumb'},
            {'rhs_id':'011', 'word':'true'},
            {'rhs_id':'012', 'word':'trade'}]

# Create grouping-variable values and indices.
# The grouping-variable values are simply
# the first two characters of the word.
lhs_allgroups = {}
rhs_allgroups = {}
for recidx in range(len(lhs_data)):
   lhs_group = lhs_data[recidx]['word'][0:2]
   if lhs_group in lhs_allgroups:
      lhs_allgroups[lhs_group].append(recidx)
   else:
      lhs_allgroups[lhs_group] = [recidx]
for recidx in range(len(rhs_data)):
   rhs_group = rhs_data[recidx]['word'][0:2]
   if rhs_group in lhs_allgroups:
      if rhs_group in rhs_allgroups:
         rhs_allgroups[rhs_group].append(recidx)
      else:
         rhs_allgroups[rhs_group] = [recidx]

# Perform the comparison using the indices
for lhs_group in lhs_allgroups:
   if lhs_group in rhs_allgroups:
      for lhs_idx in lhs_allgroups[lhs_group]:
         for rhs_idx in rhs_allgroups[lhs_group]:
            if len(lhs_data[lhs_idx]['word']) == len(rhs_data[rhs_idx]['word']):
               print(lhs_data[lhs_idx]['lhs_id'], lhs_data[lhs_idx]['word'],
                     rhs_data[rhs_idx]['rhs_id'], rhs_data[rhs_idx]['word'])
```

This is the code output, which is correct:

```
002 stop 002 step
002 stop 003 stir
003 those 009 thorn
003 those 010 thumb
```

In reality, lhs and rhs can each have millions of items. So, speed is the most important thing.

The goal is to find a faster strategy/algorithm. How do I do this faster?

The following solution also provides the correct result. However, it seems to be quite a bit slower.

```
lhs_data = np.array([('001', 'clean'),
                     ('002', 'stop'),
                     ('003', 'those')],
                    dtype=[('lhs_id', 'S3'), ('word', 'S10')])
rhs_data = np.array([('001', 'quack'),
                     ('002', 'step'),
                     ('003', 'stir'),
                     ('004', 'state'),
                     ('005', 'storm'),
                     ('006', 'thin'),
                     ('008', 'thaw'),
                     ('009', 'thorn'),
                     ('010', 'thumb'),
                     ('011', 'true'),
                     ('012', 'trade')],
                    dtype=[('rhs_id', 'S3'), ('word', 'S10')])

# Create grouping-variable values and indices.
# The grouping-variable values are simply the
# first two characters of the word.
lhs_grouping_var = np.array([row['word'][:2] for row in lhs_data])
rhs_grouping_var = np.array([row['word'][:2] for row in rhs_data])

# Get the unique values in both lhs and rhs grouping variables
lhs_unique = np.unique(lhs_grouping_var)
rhs_unique = np.unique(rhs_grouping_var)

# Get common values between lhs rhs grouping variables
common = np.intersect1d(lhs_unique, rhs_unique)

# Get the indices for each common value in lhs and rhs grouping variables
for group in common:
   lhs_idx = np.where(lhs_grouping_var == group)
   rhs_idx = np.where(rhs_grouping_var == group)
   for l in lhs_idx[0]:
      for r in rhs_idx[0]:
         if len(lhs_data[l]['word']) == len(rhs_data[r]['word']):
            print(lhs_data[l]['lhs_id'], lhs_data[l]['word'], rhs_data[r]['rhs_id'], rhs_data[r]['word'])
```

Comment: FYI, you're talking about a join, not a cartesian product.

Comment: I noticed that someone posted an answer shortly after I posted my question, but now it appears to be deleted or gone. Is there any way to get that answer back? Thanks.

Comment: Not at the moment. The answer was deleted for being the product of an AI (and apparently as an advertisement for the poster's project/company).

Comment: The deleted answer is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422949/are-all-generative-ais-banned).